# как подключить composer из проекта

Tags: php, yii2, composer

У меня в проекте (сайт на yii2) есть папка

```
/var/www/site/vendor/composer
```

Как мне подключить его чтобы можно было вытягивать библиотеки в проект? Или если это не то что нужно, создать composer для проекта?
Я попытался установить по инструкции с оф.сайта. Все установилось успешно,
но я так понял что я установил еще один composer, в папку /root (да я знаю что под рутом не надо запускать composer, но тем не менее)
библиотеки скачиваются в /root/vendor, а проект лежит в /var/www/site, как это исправить
Простите за такой вопрос, я ни разу не пользовался composer раньше.

Comment: Добрый вечер. По какой инструкции Вы устанавливали composer? Вы установили его глобально в систему? Какой ОС Вы пользуетесь?

Comment: @slo_nik Здравствуйте. я устанавливал вот так https://getcomposer.org/download/ первые 4 команды. Видимо да , я установил его глобально....? я не знаю. Система ubuntu 16.04 server

Comment: @slo_nik простите , систем ubuntu 14.04 server

Comment: Напишите мне в skype, мой логин slo_nik